# magento 2.4 - blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: javascript, magento2, mime-types

I have a third party module (HK2_Addbootstrap5) that require a on line js file.

Vendor/hk2/addboostrap5/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
    var config = {
    "paths": {
        "bootstrap523": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min",
        "bootstrap513": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min",
        "bootstrap462": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min",
    },

    map: {
        "*": {
            "customjs523": "HK2_AddBootstrap5/js/init523",
            "customjs513": "HK2_AddBootstrap5/js/init513",
            "customjs462": "HK2_AddBootstrap5/js/init462",
        }
    },

    shim: {
        'bootstrap462': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'bootstrap513': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'bootstrap523': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

when loading the page, I got the following error

```
http://www.example.com/static/frontend/Ortho/tizzyWatch/fr_FR/customjs523.js » was blocked due to MIME type (« text/html ») (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

I have the .htaccess file in ./pub/static, The allow Symlink is set to know.

Thank you for your help,